# C++ one singleton Application object

Tags: c++

This is basically what i am now using a lot in my application for accessing objects that needed to be accessed from many classes:

```
Application::getInstance()->getComponentList()
```

Still think that this is not the good way how to access objects that need to be shared among many classes.

**Question** is if there is better approach to share objects in big application.

Comment: I agree. It is not a good way. It hides dependencies and potentially introduces too much (hidden) coupling. But what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with you and juanchopanza: accessing objects via a single singleton object throughout an entire project is a poor practice since modules are supposed to have few and well-stated dependencies among them (ideally: **interfaces** or means of communication).

Also: it's easy to violate the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

There's no "do X instead of the singleton approach" solution, or no silver bullet: sometimes a singleton can really be useful but if possible: avoid it and design a clear interface instead.

Also: there isn't enough information in your question to state something more specific.

Comment: well, if there is nothing as "do X instead of singleton", then i will need to stay with it :)

Comment: @Krab it depends on your project. A common use case for a singleton is a **logging class**, and that (except rare exceptions) is a widely accepted practice.